# Sigmoid and it's dearativate

Tags: neural-network, xor, sigmoid

```
 public double Sigmoid(double x)
        {
            return 2 / (1 + Math.Exp(-2 * x)) - 1;
        }
        public double Derivative(double x)
        {
            double s = Sigmoid(x) - (Sigmoid(x)* Sigmoid(x));
            return s;
        }
```

When i train the network it is giving output:

- 0,0 = 0 it is always 0 //I dont know
- 0,1 = 0,67 and it is going up //good but after 1000 repets it gets to
  0.20 and it is goind down
- 1,0 = 0.50 and it is going up //good but after 1000 repets it gets to
  0.20 and it is goind down
- 1,1 = 0.80 and it is going up //wrong it should go down.

Where is the mistake?

Neural network (XOR and back propagation)

```
int pw = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        for (int i12 = 0; i12 < pw; i12++)
        {

            //i1 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
            // i2 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
            // desired = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);


            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    i1 = 1;
                    i2 = 1;
                    desired = 0;
                }
                else if (i == 1)
                {
                    i1 = 1;
                    i2 = 0;
                    desired = 1;
                }
                else if (i == 2)
                {
                    i1 = 0;
                    i2 = 1;
                    desired = 1;
                }
                else if (i == 3)
                {
                    i1 = 0;
                    i2 = 0;
                    desired = 0;
                }


                // double[] questions = new double[2];
                //  questions[0] = 1;
                //  questions[1] = 0;
                // Random rnd = new Random();
                //   double s = questions[rnd.Next(0, 2)];
                //  double s1 = questions[rnd.Next(0, 2)];
                // i1 = s;
                // i2 = s1;

                //hidden layer hidden values
                h1 = i1 * w1 + i2 * w2; //i1*w1+i2*w2
                h2 = i1 * w3 + i2 * w4;//i1*w3+i2*w4
                h3 = i1 * w5 + i2 * w6;//i1*w5+i2*w6;

                //hidden layer hidden values

                //VALUE OF HIDDEN LAYER
                h1v = Sigmoid(h1);
                h2v = Sigmoid(h2);
                h3v = Sigmoid(h3);
                //VALUE OF HIDDEN LAYER            

                //output final
                output = h1v * w7 + h2v * w8 + h3v * w9;
                outputS = Sigmoid(output);
                //output final

                //BACKPROPAGATION

                //MARGIN ERROR
                Error = desired - outputS; //desired-cena jaka ma byc OutputS-zgadnienta cena

                //Margin Error

                //DElta output sum
                deltaoutputsum = Derivative(output) * Error * 0.05; //output bez sigmoida i error
                                                             //Delta output sum

                //weight of w7,w8,w9.
                w7b = w7; //0.3
                w8b = w8; // 0.5
                w9b = w9;// 0.9
                w7 = w7 + deltaoutputsum * h1v; //waga w7
                w8 = w8 + deltaoutputsum * h2v; //waga w8
                w9 = w9 + deltaoutputsum * h3v; //waga w9
                                                //weights of w7,w8,w9.

                //DELTA HIDDEN SUm
                h1 = deltaoutputsum * w7b * Derivative(h1);
                h2 = deltaoutputsum * w8b * Derivative(h2);
                h3 = deltaoutputsum * w9b * Derivative(h3);
                //DELTA HIDDEN SUM

                //weights 1,2,3,4,5,6
                w1 = w1 - h1 * i1;
                w2 = w2 - h1 * i2;
                w3 = w3 - h2 * i1;
                w4 = w4 - h2 * i2;
                w5 = w5 - h3 * i1;
                w6 = w6 - h3 * i2;
```

Why after training it give:

- 1.0 == close to 0, should be close to 1
- 1.1 == close to 1,should be 0
- 0.0 == it is good, close to 0
- 0.1 == close to 0,should be close to 1

This is the code to use after training(i1 and i1 are inputs 1 or 0 )

```
i1 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text);
            i2 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox5.Text);
            //hidden layer hidden values
            h1 = i1 * w1 + i2 * w2; //i1*w1+i2*w2
            h2 = i1 * w3 + i2 * w4;//i1*w3+i2*w4
            h3 = i1 * w5 + i2 * w6;//i1*w5+i2*w6;

            //hidden layer hidden values

            //VALUE OF HIDDEN LAYER
            h1v = Sigmoid(h1);
            h2v = Sigmoid(h2);
            h3v = Sigmoid(h3);
            //VALUE OF HIDDEN LAYER            

            //output final
            output = h1v * w7 + h2v * w8 + h3v * w9;
            outputS = Sigmoid(output);
            MessageBox.Show(outputS.ToString());
```

w1-w10 are weights. h1v are valuse of hidden layers. h1 are weights of hidden layers

Comment: Sorry if I'm wrong, but see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SigmoidFunction.html Maybe there is `1 / (1 + (-1 * x))`? Very odd using -2 in sigmod.... or you use some rare sigmoid?

Comment: Sorry for typo: `return 1 / (1 + Math.Exp(-1 * x));`... maybe you tried to scale sigmoid?

Comment: I change it to your code but it is same error. For 0.1 it is going to 0 ,but it should be 1. Ill post my full code of neural network,maybe you will now where is the problem. Now it is full code. After training it should give 1.0 = close to 1, 0.0 = clsoe to 0 and so on but it is giving 1.0 = close to 0 and so on.

Comment: Do you fix derivative too? `Math.Exp(x) / Math.Pow(1.0 + Math.Exp(x), 2.0)` i think

Comment: I changed it but is is still not working good. It is giving similar output for all inputs after 40.000times training. Maybe you can modify my code to make it work?

Comment: It is from this site https://stevenmiller888.github.io/mind-how-to-build-a-neural-network/ but i dont know why it is not working